# Bootstrap Text header 3 turns white?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bibliotek</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="removed because too immature" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="list-group">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<center>
<span class="badge">Biblioteket</a>

  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#blah"><span class="badge">1</span>Pipi and the HTML world!</li></a>
  <div id="blah" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <h3>Pipi and the HTML world!</h3>
          <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Kolla på</button>
          <a href="bib.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tillbaka</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#My_Little_Pontus"><span class="badge">2</span>My Little Pontus</li></a>
  <div id="My_Little_Pontus" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <h3>My Little Pontus</h3>
          <a href="story/story1.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Kolla på</button>
          <a href="bib.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tillbaka</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Mom_and_Dad"><span class="badge">3</span>Mom and Dad In the park</li></a>
  <div id="Mom_and_Dad" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <h3>Mom and Dad In the park</h3>
          <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Kolla på</button>
          <a href="bib.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tillbaka</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#kids"><span class="badge">4</span>Kids Show the book</li></a>
  <div id="kids" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <h3>Kids Show the book</h3>
          <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Kolla på</button>
          <a href="bib.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tillbaka</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Hello_Mom"><span class="badge">5</span>Hello Mom</li></a>
  <div id="Hello_Mom" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <h3>Hello Mom</h3>
          <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Kolla på</button>
          <a href="bib.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tillbaka</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<br>
<center><a href="index.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Framsidan</button></center></a>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Hello I have a problem with Bootstrap header 3 it seems to work on one of my pages it's original color is grey but on the other page its white or and transparent.

Here is an example:
[image: Error with font.]

As you can see I had to highlight it because it was invisable any ideas?
I tried to manualy style the head but it did not work here is the code example:

Comment: Your current code is not replicating your issue. Can you create a demo of it?

Comment: @ManojKumar Sure I have included the page so it should be visible now!

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your problem. You want the modal background to be gray?

Comment: @ManojKumar I want the text to be visable not white but black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to target and override the `h3` inside `modal-content` which is white by default in Bootstrap.

```css
.modal-content h3 { /* or just .modal-content will target all the text inside to be black */
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Bibliotek</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="penis.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <center>
      <span class="badge">Biblioteket</a>

  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#blah"><span class="badge">1</span>Pipi and the HTML world!</li>
      </a>
      <div id="blah" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <h3>Pipi and the HTML world!</h3>
            <a href="#">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Kolla på</button>
              <a href="bib.html">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tillbaka</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#My_Little_Pontus"><span class="badge">2</span>My Little Pontus</li></a>
      <div id="My_Little_Pontus" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <h3>My Little Pontus</h3>
            <a href="story/story1.html">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Kolla på</button>
              <a href="bib.html">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tillbaka</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Mom_and_Dad"><span class="badge">3</span>Mom and Dad In the park</li></a>
      <div id="Mom_and_Dad" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <h3>Mom and Dad In the park</h3>
            <a href="#">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Kolla på</button>
              <a href="bib.html">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tillbaka</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#kids"><span class="badge">4</span>Kids Show the book</li></a>
      <div id="kids" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <h3>Kids Show the book</h3>
            <a href="#">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Kolla på</button>
              <a href="bib.html">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tillbaka</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Hello_Mom"><span class="badge">5</span>Hello Mom</li></a>
      <div id="Hello_Mom" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <h3>Hello Mom</h3>
            <a href="#">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Kolla på</button>
              <a href="bib.html">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tillbaka</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <br>
      <center>
        <a href="index.html">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Framsidan</button>
      </center>
      </a>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not a problem, Edgar! :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add style to the h3 tags. For example, for black text in the modal/popup:

```
<style>
.modal-content h3 {
    color: black;
}
</style>
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bibliotek</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="penis.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="list-group">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<center>
<span class="badge">Biblioteket</a>

  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#blah"><span class="badge">1</span>Pipi and the HTML world!</li></a>
  <div id="blah" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <h3>Pipi and the HTML world!</h3>
          <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Kolla på</button>
          <a href="bib.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tillbaka</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#My_Little_Pontus"><span class="badge">2</span>My Little Pontus</li></a>
  <div id="My_Little_Pontus" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <h3>My Little Pontus</h3>
          <a href="story/story1.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Kolla på</button>
          <a href="bib.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tillbaka</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Mom_and_Dad"><span class="badge">3</span>Mom and Dad In the park</li></a>
  <div id="Mom_and_Dad" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <h3>Mom and Dad In the park</h3>
          <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Kolla på</button>
          <a href="bib.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tillbaka</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#kids"><span class="badge">4</span>Kids Show the book</li></a>
  <div id="kids" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <h3>Kids Show the book</h3>
          <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Kolla på</button>
          <a href="bib.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tillbaka</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Hello_Mom"><span class="badge">5</span>Hello Mom</li></a>
  <div id="Hello_Mom" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <h3>Hello Mom</h3>
          <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Kolla på</button>
          <a href="bib.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tillbaka</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<br>
<center><a href="index.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Framsidan</button></center></a>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)